# ¿Como logro que mi funcion medallaSegunPuesto retorne el valor indicado?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio de Javascript y soy nueva en esto. El ejercicio me pide que realice una funcion de "medallasSegunPuesto" utilizando un solo if. En mi consola escribi el siguiente codigo pero me retorna error.

````
function medallaSegunPuesto(puesto){
 let medallas = ["Oro", "Plata", "Bronce","Seguí participando"];
let medallasDevuelta = medallas[puesto-1];

for(let puesto=1; puesto.length;puesto++){

 if(medallasDevuelta === puesto){
              return medallasDevuelta;
       }
}
    }```
````

Comment: Que error te da?

Answer (score 0):

Me pregunto por qué no usas simplemente el siguiente código:

```
function medallaSegunPuesto(puesto){
  let medallas = ["Oro", "Plata", "Bronce","Seguí participando"];
  let index = Math.min(Math.max(puesto - 1, 0), 3);

  return medallas[index];
}
```

Lo que hace es, le pasas un puesto del 1 al 4, a este se le resta 1 para que el primero sea 0 y con las funciones de `Math.min` y `Math.max` limitas el rango, para que puesto devuelva siempre un puesto de los 4. Si le pasas -1 por ejemplo, devuelve "Oro" o si es 6 por ejemplo, "Seguí participando"